# ROS2 Humble - Compiling msg, srv, and action use cases using .idl files

Tags: ros, ros2

I am currently involved in compiling msg, srv, and action use cases using the ROS2 Humble distribution. In my use case, I would like to generate the interface/header files using .idl files instead of using .msg, .srv, and .action files.  Additionally, my use case also includes having enums and using them inside a structure, which may be defined in the same or different .idl files.

I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide me with any resources or examples related to this specific use cases. Any help or guidance you can offer would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0):

This [documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Concepts/Advanced/About-Internal-Interfaces.html#type-specific-interfaces) page should help you understand how .idl files are generated/used in the rosidl and you can see an example in the units tests [here](https://github.com/ros2/rosidl/blob/0775e1059638dc24e7d87c0b6b51bd2c8809d678/rosidl_generator_tests/CMakeLists.txt#L33C1-L41C4) where and .idl is used where a .msg can be used.

However, in terms of enums, I don't think that is something that was ever merged in. See this [discussion](https://github.com/ros2/rosidl/issues/260).

Comment: Hello Andre, thank you for your response. I appreciate the information you provided. I was wondering if there is a guide available that offers instructions on how to write a ROS-specific IDL file. I'm looking for a resource that can provide detailed guidance and best practices for creating IDL files specifically for ROS. Thank you in advance for your assistance.